# Defining the residuals function between data from array and function: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-fitting

I have a trouble with defining the residuals function inside my code. This function is further used for leastsq process, but in this case it does not matter. I stared programming recently, so that is why my question may be silly.

There is data, where `t` is time and `d1`, `d2` - array of values for 2 processes. Negative values (`-1`) inside `d1`,`d2` mean the absence of data in that moment of time. Functions `D1`,`D2` depend on time and several parameters (`k1-k4`, which I am going to fit). Functions are defined in the program before.

```
t  = [0.5, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 90, 120, 180]
d1 = [0.145043746,0.273566338,0.437829373,0.637962531,-1,0.898107567,-1,1.186340492,1.359184345,-1,1.480552058,1.548143954]
d2 = [-1,-1,0.002701867,0.006485195,0.014034067,-1,0.06650739,-1,0.309055933,0.645945584,1.000811933,-1]
```

Here is the cycle I am trying to make work:

```
def residuals(pars, t, d1, d2):
   k1 = pars[0]
   k2 = pars[1]
   k3 = pars[2]
   k4 = pars[3]
   diff1 = []
   diff2 = []
   for t in [0.5, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 90, 120, 180]:
      value_d1_func = d1_func(t,k1,k2,k3,k4)
      value_d2_func = d2_func(t,k1,k2,k3,k4)
   for value_d1_data in d1:
      tmp1 = value_d1_func - d1
      diff1.append(tmp1)
   for value_d2_data in d2:
      tmp2 = value_d2_func - d2
      diff1.append(tmp2)
   return np.concatenate((diff1[np.where(d1!=-1)], diff2[np.where(d2!=-1)]))
```

I redacted it several times and it still does not work. The mistakes I had were:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: the cycle does not work!) I changed it several times, I had the following mistakes during compiling:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: That is crucial information that you need to include in your question.

Comment: Why are you removing essential information from your question? You did **not** get the error `TypeError: ...` you got *much more* output than that, which starts with a `Traceback` and that is only the *last* line. Please post the **whole** error message (and, please, format it like code).

Comment: What are `d1` and `d2`?

Comment: these questions appear 1000x a day on SO. read the error, look at the line number, and see where you're trying to divide an `int` by a `list` in that line. if you're still stuck, break the line down into all its component parts and examine all the variables individually. try starting out with ipython

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would post the whole traceback rather than just the last line.

There is a problem here:

```
return np.concatenate((diff1[np.where(d1!=-1)], diff2[np.where(d2!=-1)]))
```

[`np.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) always returns a `tuple` of indices. `diff1` and `diff2` are `list`s, which can only be indexed by integers or slices, hence the first error. If you convert `diff1` and `diff2` to arrays before indexing them, the first `TypeError` should go away.

I can't see you using the `/` operator anywhere in the code you've posted, so it's impossible for me to be more specific about the other `TypeError`, other than to say that somewhere in your code you're trying to divide an `int` by a `list`, which is not allowed!

The common theme seems to be that you're treating `list`s as though they were `np.ndarray`s. Don't confuse these two types - they are quite distinct!